# How to set the guides in Photoshop 2014 locked by default?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, guides

How can I set the guides locked in Photoshop 2014 by default? It's too annoying to lock the guides on every startup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a way to lock guides by default. However, the shortcuts for locking and unlocking guides are:

Cmd + Optn + ; for Mac

Ctrl + Alt + ; for PC

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: It will facilitates my life undoubtedly, but it won't solve the main task: it doesn't eliminate the necessary of a remembering a current status of the guides. Anyway, thanks for answer!